# DynamoDB gt() query on GSI

Tags: boto3, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get a `gt()` query working with a DynamoDB GSI

My Cloudformation is as follows -

```yaml
Resources
  MyTable:
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: pk
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: sk
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: my_datetime_string
        AttributeType: S
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: my_datetime_string-index
        KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: my_datetime_string
          KeyType: HASH
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: pk
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: sk
        KeyType: RANGE
      TableName:
        Fn::Sub: my-table-${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
```

My query code is as follows (python) -

```py
tablename="whatever"
import boto3
table=boto3.resource("dynamodb").Table(tablename)
from datetime import datetime
timestamp="%s 00:00:00" % datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
expr=Key("my_datetime_string").gt(timestamp)
print (table.query(IndexName="my_datetime_string-index",        
                   KeyConditionExpression=expr))
```

I have some data in the table and have can see that it has a String type (`my_datetime_string`) -

```py
{'Item': {'my_datetime_string': '2022-01-27 14:30:00', 'sk': 'HEAD', 'pk': 'EVENT#1293000'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'XXX', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Tue, 08 Feb 2022 10:54:15 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '522', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'XXX', 'x-amz-crc32': '2080419831'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

But all I get from the query is -

```sh
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported
```

What am I missing here ? Surely GSI indexes support `gt()` queries for `String` types ? (or maybe not ??)

Comment: Ps code works fine with eq() query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_datetime_string` is your index's `Partition Key` (= `Hash Key`).  A [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) must provide one-and-only-one `Partition Key` value.  This means that `eq` is a valid operator in `Partition Key` conditions, but `gt` is not.

If your table/index has a [compound primary key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/), a query can apply a `gt` operation to the `Sort Key` (= `Range Key`) condition, which will return a [range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) of values.

Comment: Super clear - thank u